# How can i connect Note 4 camera module (16M OIS) to Raspberry Pi?

Tags: camera

RPi camera directly connects to the camera port, and easy to get it running. However, the Samsung Galaxy Note 4 camera module has a very small port (which is probably slim-stack), and i am also not aware of the pin details. How can i connect it to Raspberry Pi?

[image: 16M OIS Camera Module]

Comment: There's obviously got to be a linux driver for this, since it is used on Android.  However, I very much doubt it is open source, therefore you can't compile it for the pi.  So you are probably out of luck here, unless you consider arduous reverse engineering a lucky prospect.

Comment: I guess this camera module uses MIPI 2,4 lane and Raspberry Pi uses 2-lane MIPI (probably). Have no idea if those two have matching ports (doesnt seem so). However the issue with driver seems to be a bigger problem.